# What is this plant with pink and yellow flowers?

Tags: identification, houseplants

This is a potted plant but the people who handle it cannot tell me what it is 
specifically.

This is in southern California, US.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Lantana camara - its a perennial, but is usually grown for its blooms during summer and autumn - its not frost hardy. If you get frosts where you are, you'll need to protect it during winter. The colour of the flowers change over time - more info on that here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/lantana/color-changing-lantana-flowers.htm

Comment: It does seem to be Lantana camara.  Does the scent of it cause dizziness to people?

Comment: That's not something I've heard of - its the leaves that have a scent, but they usually have to be bruised to release it. I suppose some people may react that way, as some may do to any scent or smell

Comment: Does it release pollen seasonally? It's being planted closed to my bedroom window. Pardon my questions but I am a noob in gardening.

Comment: Yes, the flowers produce pollen - in fact, this plant is considered an invasive weed in parts of the USA (Florida)  because it reproduces easily in the wild.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about the pollen - it's pollinated by insects, so the pollen is sticky and not likely to become airborne.